MOSFET driving external inductive load with high-side PTC protection and free wheeling diode
I intend to drive an inductive load across JP8 with a standard N-type MOSFET. We like to protect the high-side output with a PTC to guard against short-circuits, although our 12V supply is current-limited, we don't want the whole rail to drop to 0V.
Now, should I free wheel directly across JP8 or across both JP8 and the PTC directly into the 12V power rail ?
If the PTC opens, the free wheeling diode effectively looses its benefits temporarily.
Are there downsides to placing the diode directly across JP8 ? I was thinking of reduced ESD protection to the MOSFET drain, as perhaps a more direct path from JP8.2 to 12V through the diode (instead of through both the diode and F2) would reduce the overvoltage appearing at Q6's drain ?
What is the standard practice and why ? Perhaps another form of protection is missing in this design ?



If the PTC opens, the free wheeling diode effectively looses its
benefits temporarily

That is untrue. If the diode is across the terminals of J8 it is also across the inductive load and, when the MOSFET deactivates (or the PTC goes open circuit) the load inductor has a path that circulates current via the diode.

Are there downsides to placing the diode directly across JP8

The diode is there to burn off the flyback energy of the inductive load and this can take several to several tens of milliseconds. If that is too long then a resistor in series with the diode can help but, it increases the voltage seen at the drain from roughly one diode drop (0.7 volts) to several volts or several tens of volts depending on the resistor value.
This burns off the load inductors stored energy faster of course.

What is the standard practice and why

Standard practice is a diode across the load as this minimizes the excessive voltage seen at MOSFET drain to supply plus 0.7 volts. If the time taken to dissipate the stored energy is too long a resistor can be added in series with the diode or, in some cases, a Zener diode across drain and source is used.
I see no benefit to the diode (marked with a question mark) in your diagram.

I meant in the orange configuration if the PTC opens, then the diode does not effectively serve to free-wheel the load. One benefit of this configuration would be to dissipate the inductive load's energy faster (current forced to go through both D and F). My main concern about free-wheeling directly across the load, while the F is present and still in working order, is an ESD-like event on JP8.2 would not be brought to 12V through the diode as effectively. Q6's drain would likely experience a higher overvoltage than if the diode were connected to 12V directly.

@gsimard no, I disagree with you.

About which statement ? And why ?
